# How to convert each character to binary

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, numbers, converters

I have this problem, I would like to convert each character to a binary number according to an if the condition or another easier way. All numbers greater than or equal to 5 must convert to 1 and numbers less than or equal to 4 convert to 0.

Whole code:

```js
n = [
  '0110100000', '1001011111',
  '1110001010', '0111010101',
  '0011100110', '1010011001',
  '1101100100', '1011010100',
  '1001100111', '1000011000'
] // array of binary 

let bin = [] // converting to numbers
length = n.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  bin.push(parseInt(n[i]));

var sum = 0; // sum of all binaries
for (var i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
  sum += bin[i];
}
console.log(sum); // 7466454644

// ...
// code converting each character
// ...

// console.log(sumConverted) // 1011010100
```

How do I convert each character >= 5 to 1, and the <5 to 0?

ex:

```
7466454644
7=1, 4=0, 6=1, 6=1, 4=0, 5=1, 4=0, 6=1, 4=0, 4=0
return 1011010100
```

Comment: You have an array of **strings** that happen to include only characters "0" and "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to get the last digit from the whole number in every iteration by `last_digit = number%10` and then remove the last digit from the original number as `number = Math.ceil(number/10)` and do it until the number is equal to `0`

for example:

```
number = 123;
last_digit = 123%10 = 3
number = Math.ceil(number/10) = 12
```

```js
let num = 7466454644;

let convertedBinary = '';
while (num) {
  const number = (num % 10) < 5 ? 0 : 1;
  convertedBinary = `${number}${convertedBinary}`;
  num = Math.floor(num/10);
}

console.log(convertedBinary);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Split the number as a string and map over the digits:

```js
const sum = 7466454644;

const string = sum.toString(); // convert to string

const result = string
    .split("")                 // split to digits
    .map((x) => +(+x > 4))     // if digit is greater than 4 make it 1
    .join("");                 // join back into string
    
console.log(result);           // 1011010100
```

`+(+x > 4)` is very terse but is equivalent to `Number(Number(x) > 4)`. We're converting a boolean to a number since it'll be 0 or 1.